# bxslider working fine on chrome but on firefox, HTML is disappearing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mozilla, bxslider

Currently I am implementing a bxslider with ajax generated li's .Everything is working fine in chrome, but in firefox slider content is being disappeared.Means, everything except slider content is appearing in the page but the content in the slider doesn't render on the page.

You can check it  [here](http://www.checkbeta.com/amkette-news) .Any help will be appericiated.

Here is my code:

```
function loadPage(file_name_url, url_data, typ) {   
      var items = [];
      var page_content = $("#page-content");

$('#loading').css('visibility','visible');  
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: file_name_url,
    data: url_data,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg) {            
        if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
            switch(typ) {
                case "category":                        
                    $('#page-content').html(msg);   
                    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({});
                    //$("#cate-page-content").hide();
                    $("#cate-page-content").animate({"top": "10%", "height":"auto"}, "slow");   
                    $(".title").css("position","relative"); 
                    $(".bx-controls").css("position","fixed");  


                    //bx-controls bx-has-pager bx-has-controls-direction
                    //$('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');                 
                break;
                case "article":
                    items.push(msg);

                    $("#page-content").html(msg);
                    $("#page-content").css("overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden;");
                    $("#article-page-content").mCustomScrollbar({
                        scrollButtons:{
                            enable:true
                        }
                    });                                             
                    $("#article-page-content").animate({"left": "13%"}, "slow");
                    //$("#pageContent").show();     
                break;

            }
        }
    }       
});
 }
```

Comment: in firefox its giving error ReferenceError: adjustMenu is not defined adjustMenu();

Comment: also the website is not running on internet explorer.IE gets hanged whenever i try to run the website.

Comment: ok so first remove this error by defining adjustMenu method in nav-script.js above document.ready then check it.

Comment: dear akh please check now.I have fixed the error you just mentioned...but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, and somehow I found that in jquery.bxslider.css under bx-wrapper class, there is no width set for slider itself, so I added width:100% and it appeared immediately. That worked for me, hope it helps.

```
.bx-wrapper {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 60px;
*zoom: 1;
display: block;
border:1px solid white;
overflow: hidden;
height: 470px;
border:1px solid green;
width: 100%;
}
```